# Why i am unable to convert string to double?

Tags: c++

I have written the following code that converts a string to double.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 using namespace std;

 main()
 {
     char a[] = "13.45";
     double result; //output variable must be of 'double' type

     cout<<"Value before conversion is "<<a<<endl;

     result = atof(a);

     cout<<"Value after conversion is "<<result<<endl;
 }
```

the problem is no matter what value I declare for "a" the answer is always same as the input value.

Note: I did read all the question related to the same topic but none of them gave me a clue to solve my code.

Comment: *"...the answer is always same as the input value."* It seems, if you are trying to convert a value between types, this is exactly what you want. What behavior are you expecting and how does the current behavior differ from that?

Comment: This code [does exactly what I expect it to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07233ced3688e06b) so Im not sure what your question is...

Comment: i guess when i enter a digit like 2, it should give me the answer 2.00

Comment: how will it give me answer in decimal points? or i will have to use some other data type for it?

Comment: If you want decimal points, look into [iomanip](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/)

Comment: Where did you tell C++ to give you decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not the same.
The string "13.45" and the floating value 13.45 will be displayed in the same manner. If you want to confirm that result holds a float value try printing result+1 instead of result, it will behave like a normal float.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get that. can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: oh ok. will try that

Comment: In the console the output of  cout<<"13.45"; and cout<<13.45; will look as if there is not difference between them but in the memory the first is a string and the second is a float. To confirm this you can write cout<<answer+1; this will display 14.45 whereas writing cout<<a+1; will probably give an error. I hope this helps. If not please let me know.

Comment: Value before conversion is 13.45
In terms of string: 3.45
In terms of double: 14.45

Comment: Yup, now it's correct. Thank you so much for explaining.